# links php mysql pagination not working

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

i'm trying to paginate my results, the limit is working, the number of pages is properly set, but the links of the pagination don't work, i've been looking for a while and nothing, ¿can you take a look and tell me what i'm doing wrong? thanks

```
<?php
include("config/conexion.php");
$limit = 3;

if(isset($_GET['pag'])){
$pag= $_GET['pag'];
}else{
$pag=1;
}
$offset = ($pag-1) * $limit;


$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS id, nombre, local, telefono, celular, email FROM almacenes WHERE id_cat = '".$_GET["id"]."'";
$sqlTotal = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() as total";
$currentid = $_GET["id"];
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$rsTotal = mysql_query($sqlTotal);

$rowTotal = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsTotal);
// Total de registros sin limit
$total = $rowTotal["total"];

?>
 <?php if($_GET["id"]){  $cat = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM almacenes WHERE id_cat = '".$_GET["id"]."' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit");  if(mysql_num_rows($cat)>0){

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($cat)){ ?>   

<div class="almacenbox">
    <div class="shadow"></div>
    <div class="white">
        <div class="image"><img src=almacenes/local_111.jpg></div>
        <div class="title"><?php echo $row->nombre?></div>
        <div class="text">Local: <?php echo $row->local?></div>
        <div class="text">Teléfono: <?php echo $row->telefono?></div>
        <div class="text">Celular: <?php echo $row->celular?></div>
        <div class="text"><?php echo $row->email?></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } }else{ echo "<p>No hay resultados para mostrar</p>"; }?>
    <table border="1" bordercolor="#000">
  <tfoot>
  <tr>
     <td colspan="2">
  <?php
     $totalPag = ceil($total/$limit);
     $links = array();
     for( $i=1; $i<=$totalPag ; $i++)
     {
        $links[] = "<a href=almacenes.php?id=$currentid?pag=$i\>$i</a>"; 
     }
   echo implode(" - ", $links);
  ?>
     </td>
  </tr>
  </tfoot> </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$links[] = "<a href=almacenes.php?id=$currentid?pag=$i\>$i</a>";`

Should be

`$links[] = '<a href="almacenes.php?id=$currentid&amp;pag=$i">$i</a>';`

Query strings start with a `?` but any name-value pairs after that first one require an ampersand.

On a side note you should never place user data directly into your query.  This leaves you open to an SQL injection attack. Consider using [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or switching to the [mysqli library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: still don't work... links appear like this($i - $i...) and when i click them appears this: "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in line 72" the line with the mysql_query (this appear anyway when i click the pages)

Comment: Sounds like your query is failing.  Call `mysql_error()` after your query.

Comment: it's working! just change quotes "(x)' and '(x)" here it is:
     
      `"<a href='almacenes.php?id=$currentid&pag=$i' >$i</a>";`